# Setting an object property as State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, web-frontend

So I am trying to make an e-commerce website in react, and I am fetching data from an API, and in my single product page which displays data for individual products, I am displaying an array of images and when u click on them the image shows in the main big box, however when the page initially loads, that box is empty and I have tried setting my initial state to images[0].url/images[url].0, basically everything I could do, I can't understand how to set initial state here

In my main Single product page I have:

```js
    const Singleproduct = () => {
    const 
    {isSingleLoading,Singleprod,SingleProderr,getSingleProduct}=useGlobal();
    const {id}=useParams();
    const{ id:alias,name, 
   company,price,description,category,stock,stars,reviews,image}=Singleprod;
    const[selectedimg,setSelectedimg]=useState(null)
  
    const setimg=(image)=>{ //function to set image on click
    setSelectedimg(image);
}`
  <div className="col-lg-2 col-12 ">
     <SingleProductImage onimgclick={setimg} imgs={image}/>
  </div>
         <div className="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-center justify-content- 
    center col-12 my-auto">
                <MainImg setimg={selectedimg}/>
    </div>
```

In my image multiple images page I have

```js
 const SingleProductImage = ({onimgclick, imgs}) => {
  return (
    <>
    
 {imgs && imgs.map(
   (curEle,index)=>{
                return(
                    <>
                    <div div className="row m-auto ">
                        <div className="col-lg-auto col-sm-3 col-12 m-auto d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center mt-3">
                            <figure style={{cursor:"pointer"}} >
                                <img src={curEle.url} alt={curEle.filename} key={index} width={100} height={100} onClick={()=>{onimgclick(curEle.url)}} className='border border-3 border rounded border-success'/>
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </>)
                    }
        )
        }
    
    </>
  )
}
export default SingleProductImage
```

And in my main selected image I have:

```js
const MainImg = ({setimg}) => {
  return (
    <>
 <img src={setimg} alt='main photo' width={250} height={500} className='shadow-lg rounded border border-2 border-dark'/>
    </>
  )
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsP28.png)
This is how my page looks initially when I click on it and when u click on the images on left, they show up in the main box in the center, and I want the first image to be automatically passed to my state so it can show when the page is opened

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useEffect` to set it initially when the page loads

```
useEffect(() => {
  // code to fetch images
  setimg(image) // then set image
  }, [])
```

Comment: but the function is only invoked on click, and if I pass a default value above the on click function, it doesen't change images when i click on it

Comment: pass the images that you are fetching from api to this component, then use `useEffect` to set an image initially from the list of images. `setSelectedimg(images[0])`

Comment: I get the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0'), the object exsists and works just fine when I print it in the console, but when I have to access an individual element I get this error